# ¿Por qué mi reputación en ocasiones baja?

Tags: discusión, reputación

El día de hoy revisaba mi reputación y de pronto me encontré con que había bajado unos puntos. Realmente no es un tema con el cual tenga conflicto pero me surgieron algunas dudas al respecto:

- ¿En qué casos mi reputación puede bajar?
- ¿Dentro del sitio existe alguna sección dónde pueda ver el historial
  de mi reputación y ver las razones por las cuales ha bajado?
- ¿Realmente, qué significa la reputación?

Me parece que SO-es se está convirtiendo en una gran comunidad y me gusta contribuir al respecto.

Comment: Dentro de tu perfil se puede ver el historial de tu reputación: http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16841/flxtr?tab=reputation ... Sin embargo, no veo que se haya reducido últimamente.

Comment: Fui yo la primera vez... http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27197/13558 ... Porque era solo un enlace. Me pareció que no respondía la pregunta.

Comment: @Flxtr puede bajar por que alguien no puede estar de acuerdo con tu respuesta/pregunta la cual puede votar negativamente o puede subir cuando votan positivamente tu respuesta/pregunta.

Comment: @ArtEze de acuerdo, en aquella ocasión me quedó claro el voto negativo. Nikomaster, eso también lo entiendo, más bien, mi pregunta va orientada a que de un momento a otro bajé 4 puntos, y realmente no supe el por qué.

Comment: También te quitan un punto si votas negativamente una respuesta, o cuando aguien que habia aceptado una respuesta tuya la "desacepta" (palabra horrible que me acabo de inventar) pierdes esos puntos. De todas formas en el enlace que te ha puesto Mariano te tienen que aparecer todos los puntos de reputación y porque suman o restan.

Comment: Bien @blonfu, muchas gracias por el dato, me parece entonces que fue éso, ¡muchas gracias!